# Sort a tree data structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tree ( 
 id integer NOT NULL,
 name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
 parentid integer,
 displayorder integer NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT tree_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

[image]

> The displayorders are relative in the same parent.

I am stuck on sorting this data to have the output like this:

```
1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1 -> 1.1.2 -> 1.1.3 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2 -> 3
```

Highly appreciated if you could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive query to walk the tree. To properly apply the `displayorder` on each level, you need to also collect the path to each node, to make sorting possible:

```
with recursive all_nodes as (
   select id, name, parentid, displayorder, array[id] as path
   from tree
   where parentid is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.name, c.parentid, c.displayorder, p.path||c.id
   from tree c 
     join all_nodes p on c.parentid = p.id
)
select id, name
from all_nodes
order by path, displayorder;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/MJEL66144

Comment: Note: this probably wont work if the display orders of nodes{11,12,13} are permuted between them.(the example data is not *pathalogical* enough)

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my days! I did come up with a recursive query BUT didn't know ordering array was done by index. Very useful!!!